# Match two separate dataframes to a larger dataframe based on matching values (In Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 1 large dataframe, and 2 smaller dataframes in which I would like to append/match based on certain criteria.

**Data**

*df1* (large dataframe)

```
id  Date    pp  pos
aa  q122    200 10
aa  q222    200 10
bb  q322    500 5
bb  q422    500 5
cc  q122    100 2
cc  q222    100 2
```

*df2*

```
name    date1   count1  pp1
aa      q122    3       30
aa      q222    5       10
```

*df3*

```
ex  date2   count2  pp2
cc  q122    3       30
cc  q222    5       10
```

**Desired**

```
id  Date    pp  pos name    date1   count1  pwr1    ex  date2   count2  pwr2
aa  q122    200 10  aa      q122    3       30      NaN NaN     0       0
aa  q222    200 10  aa      q222    5       10      NaN NaN     0       0
bb  q322    500 5   NaN     NaN     0       0       NaN NaN     0       0
bb  q422    500 5   NaN     NaN     0       0       NaN NaN     0       0
cc  q122    100 2   NaN     NaN     0       0       cc  q122    3       30
cc  q222    100 2   NaN     NaN     0       0       cc  q222    5       10
```

Logic:
I am matching the individual dataframes based on whether the 'name' and 'ex' values match the
'id' value as well as the 'date'

**Doing**

```
df1['id'] = df1['name'].combine_first(df1['ex'])


out = df2.merge(df1, on=['id', 'date'], how='outer')
```

But getting a little lost on how to incorporate the 3rd dataframe
Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can chain [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) operations:

```
out = (
    df1.merge(
        df2, left_on=['id', 'Date'], right_on=['name', 'date1'], how='outer'
    ).merge(
        df3, left_on=['id', 'Date'], right_on=['ex', 'date2'], how='outer'
    )
)
```

`out`:

```
   id  Date   pp  pos name date1  count1   pp1   ex date2  count2   pp2
0  aa  q122  200   10   aa  q122     3.0  30.0  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
1  aa  q222  200   10   aa  q222     5.0  10.0  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
2  bb  q322  500    5  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
3  bb  q422  500    5  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
4  cc  q122  100    2  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   cc  q122     3.0  30.0
5  cc  q222  100    2  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   cc  q222     5.0  10.0
```

---

With [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to match exact output by filling certain columns with 0 and downcasting to `int` (if possible) and modifying column names:

```
out = (
    df1.merge(
        df2, left_on=['id', 'Date'], right_on=['name', 'date1'], how='outer'
    ).merge(
        df3, left_on=['id', 'Date'], right_on=['ex', 'date2'], how='outer'
    ).rename(
        columns={'pp1': 'pwr1', 'pp2': 'pwr2'}
    ).fillna(
        {'count1': 0, 'pwr1': 0, 'count2': 0, 'pwr2': 0}, downcast='infer'
    )
)
```

`out`:

```
   id  Date   pp  pos name date1  count1  pwr1   ex date2  count2  pwr2
0  aa  q122  200   10   aa  q122       3    30  NaN   NaN       0     0
1  aa  q222  200   10   aa  q222       5    10  NaN   NaN       0     0
2  bb  q322  500    5  NaN   NaN       0     0  NaN   NaN       0     0
3  bb  q422  500    5  NaN   NaN       0     0  NaN   NaN       0     0
4  cc  q122  100    2  NaN   NaN       0     0   cc  q122       3    30
5  cc  q222  100    2  NaN   NaN       0     0   cc  q222       5    10
```

---

DataFrames and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'cc', 'cc'],
    'Date': ['q122', 'q222', 'q322', 'q422', 'q122', 'q222'],
    'pp': [200, 200, 500, 500, 100, 100],
    'pos': [10, 10, 5, 5, 2, 2]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['aa', 'aa'],
    'date1': ['q122', 'q222'],
    'count1': [3, 5],
    'pp1': [30, 10]
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ex': ['cc', 'cc'],
    'date2': ['q122', 'q222'],
    'count2': [3, 5],
    'pp2': [30, 10]
})
```

Comment: thank you let me try this suggestion - what is the downcast infer? is this just filling the remaining columns w values

Comment: `NaN` is of type float (and columns must be of a single type). If you just `fillna` you'll end up with `0.0` (float) since the column contains whole numbers this is saying reduce the size (if possible) to the smallest supported type. Which will give you `int` in this case. If your actual data is of type float you can skip it. @Lynn

Comment: ok this makes sense- thank you for your knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Do it in two stages:

```
merged_1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=["id", "Date"], right_on=["name", "date1"], how="outer")
merged = pd.merge(merged_1, df3, left_on=["id", "Date"], right_on=["ex", "date2"], how="outer")

>>> merged
   id  Date   pp  pos name date1  count1   pp1   ex date2  count2   pp2
0  aa  q122  200   10   aa  q122     3.0  30.0  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
1  aa  q222  200   10   aa  q222     5.0  10.0  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
2  bb  q322  500    5  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
3  bb  q422  500    5  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
4  cc  q122  100    2  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   cc  q122     3.0  30.0
5  cc  q222  100    2  NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN   cc  q222     5.0  10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Must show you multiple object ids.?

If not I would use join. Code below

```
df1.set_index('id').join(df2.set_index('name')).join(df3.set_index('ex'))
```